# Randomly create various subsets with different features from the original dataset using R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with more than 300 features and a response column. I was wondering if it is possible to randomly create 4 subsets with different features using R.

For Example:

[image]

The dataset is in CSV format.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to @jpsmith answer I managed to solve the problem using the following code:

```
data <- read.csv("-----/file.csv")

label <- data$label 

subset1 <- data[, c(sample(1:300,75))]
subset1$label <- label
data = data[,!(names(data) %in% colnames(subset1))]

subset2 <- data[, c(sample(1:225,75))]
subset2$label <- label
data = data[,!(names(data) %in% colnames(subset2))]

subset3 <- data[, c(sample(1:150,75))]
subset3$label <- label
data = data[,!(names(data) %in% colnames(subset3))]

subset4 <- data
subset4$label <- label
```

If there is a way to improve the solution please post it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want random features, you can try something like this. Note this was based off of the posted image, but you mentioned your real data has 300 features. I don't know what your real dataset looks like, but you should be able to easily modify this to account for the actual dataset.

```
set.seed(123)
# create sample data
sample_data <- data.frame(id = 1:7,
                          F1 = sample(1:10,7),
                          F2 = sample(1:10,7),
                          F3 = sample(1:10,7),
                          F4 = sample(1:10,7),
                          F5 = sample(1:10,7),
                          F6 = sample(1:10,7),
                          F7 = sample(1:10,7),
                          F8 = sample(1:10,7),
                          label = sample(0:1, 7, replace = T))

# sample random factor columns
subset1 <- sample_data[, c(1,sample(2:9,2),10)]
subset2 <- sample_data[, c(1,sample(2:9,2),10)]
subset3 <- sample_data[, c(1,sample(2:9,2),10)]
subset4 <- sample_data[, c(1,sample(2:9,2),10)] 

#subset1
# id F8 F6 label
#1  1  2  1     1
#2  2  8  3     1
#3  3  9 10     1
#4  4 10  7     1
#5  5  1  6     0
#6  6  6  5     0
#7  7  5  8     1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. however, the solution produces subsets with similar features in some cases. The main goal is to have subsets with unique and randomly selected features.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying - I’m still unclear, how many features do you want in the four data subsets? Do you want all 300 features divided among the four subsets, or each subset has ‘n’ features?

Comment: Yes, I want all 300 features to be divided among the 4 subsets where each subset will have 75 randomly selected features and the response column.